# the path from 'reuest.url.path' loses something

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Context

- *node.js version*: v6.8.1
- *hapi.js version*: v15.1.1
- *os*: macOS Sierra

I use 'GET' type ajax to send an url like 'https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#chunk' which is got from an input, but there's no '#chunk' in the result from 'reuest.url.path'.

[Here](https://git.io/vPPrU) is part of my code.

How can I solve this problem? Please!

Answer (score 0):

It's right behavior.
The `fragment` (after #) part of url never pass to the server by the browser.

You can try to pass your parameters to the server by the `query` part of the url, for example:

```
https://example.com/something/?chunk=true
```

Comment: Just know the reason. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Reopened the [issue](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3363). Please take a look. That would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Fragments Are not Sent in HTTP Request (whether the address bar by or ajax) Messages . Anything After the First `#` is a Fragment Identifier. You should read 《[6 Things You Should Know About Fragment URLs](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/)》.